# System.InvalidCastException thrown

Tags: vb.net

I'm programming a slideshow in Visual basic and get a SystemInvalidCastException when trying to initialize an array through a For Each loop.

Here's what I'm trying to do. I have an array of Images() and another array of ImageNames(). Now I store all my images on a website, let's say example.com/images, so for ease of use, I've named all my images in this manner:

```
john.jpg  
jack.jpg  
jill.jpg
```

And my ImageNames is an array which holds the list of names (leaving out ".jpg"), I was hoping that with this method I could fetch any image from the website by simply inserting its name into ImageNames, as long as there is a corresponding image. Am I wrong?

So, in my For Each loop, I'm using a simple loop to initialize my Images() array by using the names in ImageNames, like this:

```
    Dim Images() as String
    Dim ImageNames() as String = {"john", "jack", "jill"}

    Dim i as String

    For Each i In ImageNames
        Images(i) = "http://example.com/images/" & ImageNames(i) & ".jpg"
    Next
```

This is giving me a very strange error that I have no idea how to fix. I've tried converting every possible thing, changing the data types, using a different loop structure, etc... I've been stumped on this since last night and I've pretty obsessed over it since then. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What does your array of ImageNames hold?  Unless it's int's I don't think you'll be able to use it as an indexer on your Images() array.

EDIT, sorry just totally glossed over the the part where you talk about ImageNames().  Assuming Images() is a simple array you won't be able to reference the items in the array that way.  Does ImageNames.Length == Images.Length?

I'm very rusty on VB syntax, so this probably won't compile as is, but instead of a ForEach, you can do this:

```
Dim ImageNames() as String = {"john", "jack", "jill"}
Dim Images() as String= new String(ImageNames.Length){}

For i as Integer = 1 to Images.Length
    Images(i) = "http://example.com/images/" & ImageNames(i) & ".jpg"
Next
```

Comment: It holds the actual names of all the images I wish to fetch (leaving out the extension.)

Comment: Okay, I'm lost here. Why is that, exactly? The error isn't giving me any information. Is there an alternative to what I want to do?

Comment: Images() is an empty array. I'm trying to initialize it on the form load with the For Each loop. Is there a different approach to this?

Comment: in the code snippet you're showing, you're are trying to access Element # in your images array using the name of the image to try and figure out which # you want, and that's not going to work because VB is unable to translate "john", "jack", etc... into valid numbers.  That is most likely where the cast is failing.

Comment: yeah give me a minute to write something simple.

Comment: Thanks a ton. I'm fine with trying out a different implementation, I just need a programmatic approach to this. Filling out Images() with the actual links to every image would be very time consuming.

Comment: I'm still getting that error after messing with it a few times. This is really bugging me.

Comment: post the updated code and the stack trace you get from the error and we'll keep looking at it.

Comment: It's really still the same thing; something is trying to convert the first item in my ImageNames() array to an Integer.

Comment: then we need some more code, the small snippet above isn't enough to get a full picture of what's happening.

Comment: i needs to be an Integer if you are going to use it insside the loop like that

Comment: According to my Visual Basic book, in a For Each loop it should be the same data type as the array I'm indexing. And this has always worked for me until now.

Comment: Like I said, I'm rusty in vb syntax, but that doesn't sound right.  Basic arrays have to be indexed by number, can't be done with a string.

Comment: I get the same error whether it is an Integer or String, so I don't think it matters too much. Has anyone ever had this problem?

Comment: Just saying Dim i as Integer won't cut it, the data in ImageNames being used to populate i is still String objects and it will blow up doing a cast like it's doing now.

Comment: @Zack, change your loop to "For Each i As Integer..."  That will let the compiler explain to you what you're doing wrong

Comment: This is really all I'm getting: Conversion from string "john" to type 'Integer' is not valid.

Comment: See the solution above for an alternative (Have edited my initial response).  An array's index has to be numeric (specifically integer).  You are attempting to access the array with a non-numeric index; i.e. "John".  You get the exception because the compiler realises "John" isn't an integer and attempts to convert it to one using something similar to Cint("John").  Running this would give you the same exception as the one you are seeing.  Does that make better sense?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but I really wouldn't want to do this unless it was implemented in a loop. I'm not sure how I'd do that with your example, so I'm just going to manually enter the links in the array for now until I find my own solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to index your images, why not use a Dictionary/HashTable/etc.

```
Dim images As Dictionary(of Long, Object)  ' Change object to whatever type your image is
images = New Dictionary(Of Long, Object) ' Be sure to initialise the collection
images.Add(1, myImage1) 'Add an image
images.Add(2, myImage2) 'Add another image

Dim ret As Object  'If you now want to fetch an image from the dictionary...
If images.ContainsKey(1) Then ret = images(1)
```

EDIT:

The problem with your current code is that you are relying on the Images() and ImageNames() arrays staying in sync with each other.  That's quite likely a bad idea when you have lots of options at your disposal to keep these pieces of information linked together properly (as opposed to Array1(i) should relate to Array2(i)).

Having re-read your post, and sticking to my guns on the dictionary idea above, see the following...

```
Public Sub DictionaryAnswer()

    ' This is your current ImageNames array in list form
    Dim imageNames As List(Of String) = New List(Of String) From {"Jack", "Jill", "John"}

    ' To show both implementations, here it is in array form again
    Dim imageNamesArray() As String = imageNames.ToArray

    ' IWe create a format for your base address - {0} will be replaced by the image name
    Dim baseAddressFormat As String = "http://example.com/images/{0}.jpg"

    ' This is how you would add a list of names to a dictionary
    Dim imagesFromList As Dictionary(Of String, String) = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    imageNames.ForEach(Sub(n) imagesFromList.Add(n, String.Format(baseAddressFormat, n)))

    ' And similarly for your array
    Dim imagesFromArray As Dictionary(Of String, String) = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    imageNamesArray.ToList.ForEach(Sub(n) imagesFromArray.Add(n, String.Format(baseAddressFormat, n)))

    ' You can now get the url's for your images by name by doing something like:
    Dim jillsImage As String
    If imagesFromList.ContainsKey("Jill") Then jillsImage = imagesFromList("Jill")
    Dim jacksImage As String
    If imagesFromArray.ContainsKey("Jack") Then jacksImage = imagesFromArray("Jack")

End Sub
```

Hope that clears up what I meant...

EDIT #15: One day I'll work out how to get the lovely code formatting to actually work...

Comment: That seems just as inefficient as listing the links to each individual image in the Image() array. Thanks for trying to help, but I'd much rather use a loop for this.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has two problems. The first is here:

> ImageNames(i)

In that code, "i" is **not** an index. It is the actual string in the array.  Instead, you want this:

```
"http://example.com/images/" & i & ".jpg"
```

The second problem is here:

> Dim Images() as String

This goes deeper than just declaring an array with no strings in it: it's an array with no *places* for strings — an array of size zero. There are a couple ways you can fix this. In this case, it looks like you're used to working with collections rather than arrays (perhaps you've used a different language like javascript or php that incorrectly labels collections as arrays). With that in mind, I'd change your code to use a collection, like this:

```
Dim Images as New List(Of String)()
Dim ImageNames() as String = {"john", "jack", "jill"}

For Each i As String In ImageNames
    Images.Add("http://example.com/images/" & i & ".jpg")
Next
```

But that's just a re-write of your existing code. If I were to start fresh, I'd write it like this:

```
Dim ImageNames() as String = {"john", "jack", "jill"}
ImageNames.Select(Function(s) String.Format("http://example.com/images/{0}.jpg", s))
```